Observance Range
Question: Find the smallest value of
$n$ such that if we generate
$n$ IID $Unif
(0,1)$ random variables, the probability that at least one of them lies in the interval
$(0.48,0.52)$ is at least
$99
\%$
What is wrong with this line of reasoning:

Let $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$ be IID $Unif(0,1)$ random variables.
P(at least one of them lies in interval) = $P(X_1\in (0.48, 0.52) \cup X_2\in (0.48, 0.52) \cup ... \cup X_n \in (0.48, 0.52))$
= $nP(X_1\in (0.48, 0.52)) = n(P(X_1\lt  0.52) - P(X_1\le 0.48)) = 0.04n$
We want $0.04n \ge 0.99$ so $n=25$

The answers consider the intersection instead of the union and get $n=113$ but I am not sure why this method doesn't work.

When you go from step 2 to 3 you assume that the probability of the union of events is the sum of the probabilities, however this is not true in general, not even assuming the events are independent.
Instead, consider the events $A_j=\{X_j \in (0.48,0.52)\}$ and observe that
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}
P(A_1\cup\dots\cup A_N)&=1-P((A_1\cup\dots\cup A_N)^c)\\
&=1 - P(A_1^c \cap \dots\cap A_N^c)\\
&=1 - \prod_{j=1}^N P(A_j^c)\\
&=1 - (1-0.04)^N,
\end{array}
\end{equation}
where we have used that the probability of the intersection is the product of the probabilities for independent events.
Can you take it from there? :)
